Why are GeoTIFF files all white in image viewers?
In any image editor (GIMP and paint.net tried) or viewer in Windows, including using the .net framework, when opening a GeoTIFF formatted file the image width and height are correct, but there is no data, all pixels are 255 255 255. I understand that the GeoTIFF file strictly follows the TIFF format, but still their images are not viewable.
Why is this? I can see with a HEX editor that the files are full of data, but no systems seem capable of accessing it.

Any GeoTIFF file I've downloaded opens immediately in IrfanView. Can you give an example of the file you're trying to view?

Yes, try IrfanView, and also, list each and every one of the image editors and viewers you have tried so far, as well as give some info about where these files are coming from. We do not currently have enough information to answer the question you have asked; use the EDIT button to fix this.

I have discovered that GIMP can open the files, however it doesn't immediately scale the data to 0-255, just truncates the 32 bit values. Alternately is sees the 'out-of-bounds' values as error state, replacing them with a default value.
